# OnSwipeRefreshLayout doesn't stop refreshing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have an OnSwipeRefreshLayout on a RecyclerView in a fragment. The fragment implements OnRefreshListener. I call a method from the fragment as the refresh method. I found out that it won't set the OnRefreshlistener, even though there are no errors. In the app, it won't stop refreshing because the  OnRefreshListener never gets set.

xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/SwipeRefresher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/channel_list"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public static class tabFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    public int tabPosition=0;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ChannelAdapter mAdapter;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;


    public void updateData(){
        mAdapter.retrieveData();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState = getArguments();
        tabPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

    }

    public void refreshData(){
        mAdapter.retrieveData();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_main, container, false);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.SwipeRefresher);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getContext());
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent));


        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.channel_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ChannelAdapter(tabPosition, new ChannelAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String channel, int tabPosition) {
                switch (tabPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Messenger.class);
                        intent.putExtra("currentChannel", channel);
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //todo: display channel information probably
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //request user info
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refreshData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a separate object

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getContext());
```

which has nothing to do with the layout on screen instead use the previous reference which is using `findViewById` to obtain reference from the `v` View which will be displayed as layout of the fragment so

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.SwipeRefresher);
    // mSwipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getContext()); remove this
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! weird I tried that before, but it kept saying that mSwipeRefreshLayout was null. Probably because I was using getActivity() instead of v to find the view. I don't know how that changes it though.

Answer (score 1):

just comment this line

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getContext());
```

the above line creates a new instance of SwipeRefreshLayout, so the mSwipeRefreshLayout  will refer to another object, not the mSwipeRefreshLayout that in your fragment